# htaccess subdomain to folder redirection

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdomain

I need to redirect (transparent) http://test.mywebsite.com to http://mywebsite.com/test

In Apache2, I edited mywebsite.com.conf file by adding **ServerAlias *.mywebsite.com** in VirtualHost section. Then, I restarted Apache service, in webmin.

Finally, I created a new .htaccess rule :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mywebsite.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.mywebsite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mywebsite.com/test/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But, I have a **Page not found** error, and now I don't know what to do...

Any advice ? Thanks.

**EDIT**

Here is the full .htaccess file :

```
SetEnv REGISTER_GLOBALS 0

# MASK FILES IN DIRECTORIES
Options -Indexes
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mywebsite.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.mywebsite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mywebsite.com/test/$1 [L,R=301]
```

**EDIT 2**

Here is my VirtualHost file :

```
<VirtualHost ***.***.***.***:80>
SuexecUserGroup "#1011" "#1008"
ServerName mywebsite.com
ServerAlias www.mywebsite.com
ServerAlias webmail.mywebsite.com
ServerAlias admin.mywebsite.com
ServerAlias *.mywebsite.com
DocumentRoot /home/mywebsite/public_html
ErrorLog /var/log/virtualmin/mywebsite.com_error_log
CustomLog /var/log/virtualmin/mywebsite.com_access_log combined
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/mywebsite/cgi-bin/
ScriptAlias /awstats/ /home/mywebsite/cgi-bin/
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php index.php4 index.php5
<Directory /home/mywebsite/public_html>
Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
allow from all
AllowOverride All
AddHandler fcgid-script .php
AddHandler fcgid-script .php5
FCGIWrapper /home/mywebsite/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .php
FCGIWrapper /home/mywebsite/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi .php5
</Directory>
<Directory /home/mywebsite/cgi-bin>
allow from all
</Directory>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =webmail.mywebsite.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://mywebsite.com:20000/ [R]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =admin.mywebsite.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://mywebsite.com:10000/ [R]
RemoveHandler .php
RemoveHandler .php5
IPCCommTimeout 31
FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824
<Files awstats.pl>
AuthName "mywebsite.com statistics"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/mywebsite/.awstats-htpasswd
require valid-user
</Files>
RedirectMatch /cgi-bin/mailman/([^/\.]*)(.cgi)?(.*) https://mywebsite.com:10000/virtualmin-mailman/unauthenticated/$1.cgi$3
RedirectMatch /mailman/([^/\.]*)(.cgi)?(.*) https://mywebsite.com:10000/virtualmin-mailman/unauthenticated/$1.cgi$3
Alias /pipermail /var/lib/mailman/archives/public
</VirtualHost>
```

**EDIT 3**

I want to simplify my question, so here is a new challenge. This way we don't care about a folder redirection anymore, but just the variable as a subdomain. So, I tried to write another rule to redirect http://test.mywebsite.com to http://mywebsite.com?sub=test. Here is my (non working rule) :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.mywebsite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://mywebsite.com/index.php?sub=$1 [L,R=301]
```

This rule redirects **test.mywebsite.com** to **mywebsite.com/index.php?sub=**

Comment: Does your `.htaccess` have anything else? Does the folder `test` exists? Does the file or address accessed exists?

Comment: The folder test exists, and the address (mywebsite.com) too. I updated the question with full .htaccess.

Comment: And if you create a file named `test.html` inside the test folder and access `test.domain.com/test.html` does it work, giving your current rule it should send you to `www.domain.com/test/test.html`? Also you don't need `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mywebsite.com$ [NC]` on your second rule, as the next condition is already saying if HTTP starts with `test.domain.com` send it there.

Comment: When you get `Page not found error` what URL does it show in the browser?

Comment: @Prix: It doesn't work.

Comment: @anubhava: The error URL is test.mywebsite.com.

Comment: @Sumurai8: I've added my VirtualHost file.

Comment: @SergentPepper your current rule is not a transparent redirect, it should send you to `http://www.domain.com/test/test.html` if you had accessed `http://test.domain.com/test.html` if that gives you a 404 error then the folder test or file `test/test.html` does not exist within the `public_html` so the first challenge is to get that working prior trying any other rules. Also make sure you try a new browser or change your rule to `R=302` so that you're not cached from previous attempts or use a different browser other than the one you've been using so far.

Comment: **Also make sure you don't have any other `.htaccess` hidden in other folders such as the test folder.**

Comment: I am suspecting your `test.domain.com` is using a different `DocumentRoot`. You haven't shown `VirtualHost` entry of `test.domain.com`

Comment: @SergentPepper and what happens when you execute that rule you have on the EDIT 3? does the URL change when you access `http://test.domain.com/something`? If the URL does not change then `test.domain.com` is inside a `VirtualHost` that precedes the one you have posted above and as such your `.htaccess` would not work.

Comment: @anubhava: I didn't create a sub-server from webmin. So I don't have a special VirtualHost for test.mywebsite.com.

Comment: @Prix: When I go to http://test.mywebsite.com, it redirects to http://mywebsite.com/index.php?sub=

Comment: then what happens when u go there?

Comment: @Prix: After emptying my cache, the rule is finally working ! But, as you told it, it's not transparent. Do you kwow how to keep test.mywebsite.com instead mywebsite.com/test ? Or even test.mywebsite.com instead mywebsite.com/index.php?sub=test ?